# User authentication against multiple AD groups using tomcat and JNDI

Tags: tomcat, authentication, active-directory, jndi, server.xml

I am hoping someone can help me out with this or at least confirm that it can be done.

**Currently**, for my web application , when the user submits their login information, I authenticate them against an Active directory using tomcat server.xml JNDI Realm configuration.

**This is the current config:**

```
Realm 
alternateURL="ldaps://xxx.yyy.com:ddd" 
className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
connectionName="CN=ggg,OU=Generic_IDs,OU=Users,OU=hhh,DC=jjj,DC=com" 
connectionPassword="pppp" 
connectionURL="ldaps://fff.yyy.com:ddd" 
roleBase="ou=Managed_Groups,ou=Groups,ou=hhh Inc,dc=jjj,dc=com" 
roleName="cn" 
roleSearch="(member={0})" 
roleSubtree="false" 
userBase="ou=hhh,dc=jjj,dc=com" 
userRoleName="(member={0})" 
userSearch="(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(objectClass=user))" 
userSubtree="true"
```

**My Requirement:** Now, we have some users who are set up in another Active Directory, on a separate server. I need a way for the server to first try and autheticate the user against the first AD server and if not succesfull, connect to the second AD and authenticate the user the user against that. If authentiation fails here then display the access denied page.

Is there a way to do this?

Would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used the next realm tags

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm" >
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
        connectionURL="ldap://dc01.domain.com:3268"
        useDelegatedCredential="true"
        userBase="cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com"
        userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
        userRoleName="memberOf"
        roleSubtree="true"
        roleName="cn"
        roleSearch="(member={0})"
        commonRole="test1"
        roleNested="true" />

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
        connectionURL="ldap://dc01.domain.com:3268"
        useDelegatedCredential="true"
        userBase="cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com"
        userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
        userRoleName="memberOf"
        roleSubtree="true"
        roleName="cn"
        roleSearch="(member={0})"
        commonRole="test2"
        roleNested="true" />
</Realm>
```

Comment: Hi Richy, are you able to explain this a bit more please? Seems like a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/ and your uses will be happy.